# Issue while writting the data using write system call in linux

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, operating-system

I've written the example code for read,write system call in linux....Executed without any issues.

As a result,storing the buffer data into a file....

Expected result to be stored in a file is Hello World!..But i'm getting the data in a file like this Hello World!^@

What shall i need to do inorder to get the expected result?

```
int main(int argc , char *argv[])
{
        int fd;
        char buff[14];
        fd = open("myfile.txt",O_CREAT| O_WRONLY,0777);

        if(fd == -1)
        {
                printf("Failed to open the file to write");
                exit(0);
        }

        write(fd,"Hello World!\n",13);
        close(fd);

        fd = open("myfile.txt",O_RDONLY,0777);

        if(fd == -1)
        {
                printf("Failed to open the file to read");
                exit(0);
        }

        read(fd,buff,14);
        buff[14] = '\0';
        close(fd); 
        printf("Buff is %s\n",buff);

        return 0;
}
```

Comment: `buff[14] = '\0';` --> `buff[13] = '\0';`

Comment: Did you make any recompilation or rebuild?

Answer (score 2):

You declare `buff` to be 14 characters, but you write the terminator at position 15. That leads to *two* instances of [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior): One because you write out of bounds of the array, and one because when you print the buffer you have uninitialized data at position 14.